# How to create a list of 4 dataframes with size (n,3) with the 3 columns being 3 nested lists?

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop, list-comprehension, nested-lists

For my application I have 3 lists (`start_timestamps`, `end_timestamps`, and `labels`) with each list consisting of 4 nested lists with different sizes (with every nested list containing observations of a patient, so 4 patients in total).

Now I want to create a list that contains 4 dataframes (one for every patient) with every dataframe having the size of (n,3) with n being the number of observations and 3 being the `start_time`, `end_time` and `labels` columns.

I was thinking to do it with list comprehensions:

```
patients = [
    [pd.DataFrame(list(zip(start, end, label)))
     for start in patient for end in patient for label in patient]
    for patient in start_timestamps
    for patient in end_timestamps
    for patient in labels
]
```

However this doesn't even give me an output, it takes way too long to run.

Any python experts that could help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with list comprehension with the following line if the order of attributes are the same in each list:

```
dfs = [
    pd.DataFrame([[st, et, l] 
                  for st, et, l in zip(s_times, e_times, label_chunk)],
                 columns=['start_time', 'end_time', 'labels'])
    for s_times, e_times, label_chunk in zip(st_list, et_list, l_list)]
```

(Didn't run it)

However, this solution is hard to read. I'd recommend extracting the higher-level comprehension into a for loop.
Another recommendation: store each patient's data in one dataframe. Easier to handle, to read and more convenient.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Indeed storing each patient's data in one dataframe is easier, especially now I only have 4 patients. However, I am still collecting patient data so this algorithm should also work for 100+ patients.. That's why I wanted to do it in a loop.

But can you please show me how you would extract the higher-level comprehension into a for loop if you think that is better? Thnx in advance!